# how to make a form with grid view pop out with populated data, appear when a button is pressed in c#.net

Tags: winforms, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, datagridview

I guess I need to write code in this button click event to get my desired output, but unable write down the steps. Any help from you guys would be helpful and will make me learn. Thank you.

```
 private void btnViewAllEntries_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from DirDetails");
        con.Open();


        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(DetailsView.cs);//DetailsView.cs is winform with gridview
    }
```

Comment: OK so you have most of your code, what happens when you run that? what about it hasnt worked?

Comment: no it hasn't , Im unable to populate data into gridview which is another form and unable to popout that form when "view all entries" button is pressed. [MessageBox.Show(DetailsView.cs) isn't working]

Comment: (feeling like this is trying to push water up stream) why are you unable to populated data into a gridview in another form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `MessageBox` just shows messages, not `Form`s.
To show a Form you should instantiate it and use `Show` or `ShowDialog` methods.

```
DetailsView frm=new DetailsView();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Second, run the query in the `DetailsView.cs`

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Helper.ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from DirDetails", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        datagridview1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that really worked.. your help made me put my steps in order.

Comment: @sri: u r welcome again! Mark this as answer by clicking on the check mark on the left ;)

Comment: @ehsanarc: a pop up shows as  I need to have reputation of at least 15 and I only 10 mate. I would mark it once I cross 15R :)